# Blocking JS file from downloading in JSF application using Jboss server

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jboss5.x

Can we block user from downloading js/css file by directing typing URL in web browser like http://www.abc.com/resource/test.js

All these files are located in resource folder.

Web Server : Jboss 4.3 , JSF 1.2

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to do it. If you block their access, then the browser won't be able to download it as well and you end up with a CSS/JS-less page.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them under `WEB-INF`,

If you keep them in public space you need to put a  Filter to take care of this. Instead make it choose above approach .

Answer (score 0):

The browser retrieves the files in just the same way, so blocking the direct URL is blocking them forever; for manually retrieval and as part of the page.

One possible way to do this, is to make sure the user is bound to a session. At the page level, you create the session. For the resources of that page, you first check if the session exists.
Or you create a temporary ID that will allow the retrieval of the resource of a limited time.

Does not seem wise to do this, though. It can easily be evaded and when retrieving the page, clients can also view the source.